# error to link myLib.dylib with myApp.appex : dyld[46627]: Library not loaded: @rpath/myLib.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-app-extension

I tried to link one of my library in my macOS app with it's extension. But when I try to debug the app extension a link error occurs.

---

My App is built in
**Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app**,
and app extension for quick look thumbnail is in
**Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/MyApp.appex**.

I want to link myLib.dylib in
**Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyCompany/Bin** with MyApp.appex.

I tried several "runpath search path" in Build Settings of MyApp.appex like the followings:

```
@executable_path/../
@executable_path/../../../Frameworks/MyCompany/Bin/
$(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/Contents/MyCompany/Bin
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Contents/Frameworks/ 
@rpath
```

and all failed. When I run myApp.appex for debugging I have the error message :

dyld[46627]: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyLib.dylib

What should I do?